# how do i get my json to look like this (ie, correct format)?

Tags: php, json

I cant figure out how to get my json properly formatted. It needs to look like this:

```
{
    "6879": {
        "ObjectType": "TestObject",
        "RANDOM_NUMBER": [
            {
                "id": "d1df259b",
                "public_key": "94cd47c02bafe187b1ad5fb7123db486bb497195014cecad5c3e6011d5e7f101",
                "signature_1":"d1df259b4b4cf50ca84c6dc96eda8ce5742b0793c49ce65e149b69107e7f2219",
                "signature_2":"100c4b38735b54693e84d3bdec2ab1ae372e62e9149c66e6cc59d2f491076f0e",
                "number":2272314318649258607
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

heres as close as i can get:

```
{
   "6879":{
      "ObjectType":"TestObject",
      "0":{
         "RANDOM_NUMBER":[
            {
               "id":"c3838da0",
               "public_key":"94cd47c02bafe187b1ad5fb7123db486bb497195014cecad5c3e6011d5e7f101",
               "signature_1":"c3838da00a125de562bcbfaaaf87a1cfbee79cc4565f8d6eeab60be91590dade",
               "signature_2":"f9e67bc3238e57d6c1acf6c23d516b1ae858f54903e4e608892ef880ba72c002",
               "number":7974662792404963222
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

the code that gets us there is this (generate random is the function that generate all the json below the random_number array):

```
$beacon_id  = "6879";
    $title      = "RANDOM_NUMBER";
    $rn = generate_random();
    $data = json_encode(array($beacon_id => array("ObjectType" => "TestObject", array($title => array($rn)))))
```

so i need to figure out how to move this

> array($title => array($rn))

out of the array that contains the objecttype and get rid of the "0" array that contains random_number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the `array()` before `$title`:

```
$beacon_id  = "6879";
$title      = "RANDOM_NUMBER";
$rn = generate_random();
$data = json_encode(array($beacon_id => array("ObjectType" => "TestObject", $title => array($rn))));
```